# singleLinkedlist c++ segmentation fault core dumped

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a single linked list but the above code is giving an error: segmentation fault core dumped. I am inserting elements 5,9,12 in the singlelinkedlist and displaying the list. First I create a node and then class singlelinkedlist with all the methods. I am still trying to learn basics.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Node
{
    public:
    int data;
    Node* next;
    Node()
    {
    }
    Node(int element)
    {
        data = element;
        next=NULL;
    }
    Node(int element, Node* link)
    {
        data = element;
        next = link;
    }
};
class SingleLinkedList
{
    public:
    Node* head;
    int listsize = 0;
    Node* curr;
    bool isempty() 
    {
        return head==NULL;
    }
    void Insert(int data)
    {
        Node* new_node = new Node(data);
        if(isempty())
        {
             head = new_node;
             listsize++;
             return;
        }
        curr = head;
        while(curr->next!=NULL)
        {
            curr->next=curr;
        }
        curr->next=new_node;
        listsize++;
        
    }
    void display()
    {
        curr = head;
        while(curr!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<curr->data<<"-->";
            curr=curr->next;
        }
    }
    
};
int main()
{
    SingleLinkedList l1;
    l1.Insert(5);
    l1.Insert(9);
    l1.Insert(12);
    l1.display();
}
```

Comment: Did you try running the debugger on the core to see when and why the segfault occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change:

```
 while (curr->next != NULL)
 {
     curr->next = curr;
 }
```

to:

```
while (curr->next != NULL)
 {
     curr = curr->next;
 }
```

for you list traversal while doing node insertion **to avoid infinite loop**

Comment: apart from segmentation fault, this is to avoid infinite loop in your code.

Comment: Well spotted, but there’s another problem before ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The pointer `head` is not initialized. Its value is not garanteed to be `nullptr`. Your code is therefore UB, since the first insert in the list will invoke `isempty()`, which is using this uninitialised pointer.

When this is done, consider also [Anon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65970250/3723423)’s answer.